# Datastructure for quizgame with quetionbased score

Tags: json, database-design, relational-database

I am building a simple demopage where webgl quizgames will inject and get data from entities.
What I need are entities with attributes that vary from user to another.

Idea:

[image: Idea]

So I've done some tests and studying with simple json but biggest problem is when I need to have specific user score for each user for each question. One approach would be ofc making another datastructure/object for score with matching index but that would make things messier on webglclient side.

Answer (score 0):

Another object for score is the right approach, You should always think about the expansion of the entities along and not laterally, that why a relation of user and question with another score object is for my opinion the right approach.